# WindowIcon not showing up despite being valid in resource (and used elsewhere)

Tags: qt, icons, titlebar

In my last question ([Qt/C++: Icons not showing up when program is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114418/qt-c-icons-not-showing-up-when-program-is-run)) I asked how to get an icon to show up on a toolbar and was told I needed a Qt Resource, which I added and that fixed my problem, the icon did show up on the toolbar.

Now I'm trying to set the title icon of a window, using the same resource file, and it shows up fine in the Qt preview viewer but blank in the actual program. I am using a MainWindow which has an MDIArea and the children are MainWindows as well; neither the parent MDI nor child MDI windows icons will show properly. On the parent, I see the regular "Windows Application icon" and on the child, the icon is completely blank.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you set the icon?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to go through a standard resource file for windows. (That is, a .rc)

The process (as described [in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/appicon.html)) is:

> Store the ICO file in your application's source code directory, for
>   example, with the name myappico.ico. Then, create a text file called,
>   say, myapp.rc in which you put a single line of text:
>
> IDI_ICON1 ICON    DISCARDABLE     "myappico.ico"
>
> Finally, assuming you are using qmake to generate your makefiles, add this line to your myapp.pro
>
> file:  RC_FILE = myapp.rc
>
> Regenerate your makefile and your application. The .exe file will now be represented with your icon in Explorer.

In the Visual Studio case you're simply able to add a resource to your project.